# Re-creating a scatter plot(s), changing background colours and layout

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to create something similar to this plot:

[image]

I have managed to create the first 3 scatter plots and now I would like to try and replicate the image.

1. Add horizontal and vertical lines
2. colour backgrounds
3. add circles (at the points "% Add circle around here")

Any help would be great

Tex document:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% basic scatter plot %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% plot 1: base plot
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfplotsset{
      scale only axis,
  }
  \begin{axis}[
    xlabel=$A$,
    ylabel=$B$,
  ]
    \addplot[only marks, mark=+, mark size=6pt, ultra thick, color = blue]
    coordinates{ % + data
      (0.05,0.50)
      (0.10,0.15)
      (0.30,0.85)
      (0.45, 0.95)
      (0.60, 0.75)
    }; %\label{plot_one}
    \addplot[only marks, mark=-, mark size=6pt, ultra thick, color = red]
    coordinates{ % + data
      (0.20,0.05)
      (0.25,0.60)
      (0.55,0.40)
      (0.90, 0.85)
      (0.90, 0.15)
    };
    % plot 1 legend entry
    %\addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=plot_one}
   \addlegendentry{D 1}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

% plot 2: adjusted plot
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfplotsset{
      scale only axis,
  }
  \begin{axis}[
    xlabel=$A$,
    ylabel=$B$,
  ]
    \addplot[only marks, mark=+, mark size=4pt, ultra thick, color = blue]
    coordinates{ % + data
      (0.05,0.50)
      (0.10,0.15)
      };
    \addplot[only marks, mark=+, mark size=8pt, ultra thick, color = blue]
    coordinates{ % + data
      (0.30,0.85)
      (0.45, 0.95)
      (0.60, 0.75)
    }; %\label{plot_one}
    \addplot[only marks, mark=-, mark size=4pt, ultra thick, color = red]
    coordinates{ % + data
      (0.20,0.05)
      (0.25,0.60)
      (0.55,0.40)
      (0.90, 0.85)
      (0.90, 0.15)
    };
    % plot 1 legend entry
    %\addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=plot_one}
   \addlegendentry{D 2}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


% plot 3: adjusted plot
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfplotsset{
      scale only axis,
  }
  \begin{axis}[
    xlabel=$A$,
    ylabel=$B$,
  ]
    \addplot[only marks, mark=+, mark size=4pt, ultra thick, color = blue]
    coordinates{ % + data
      (0.05,0.50)              % Add circle around here
      (0.10,0.15)              % Add circle around here
      };
    \addplot[only marks, mark=+, mark size=6pt, ultra thick, color = blue]
    coordinates{ % + data
      (0.30,0.85)
      (0.45, 0.95)
      (0.60, 0.75)
    }; %\label{plot_one}
    \addplot[only marks, mark=-, mark size=8pt, ultra thick, color = red]
    coordinates{ % - data
      (0.20,0.05)
      (0.25,0.60)
      (0.55,0.40)
      };
      \addplot[only marks, mark=-, mark size=2pt, ultra thick, color = red]
    coordinates{ % - data
      (0.90, 0.85)             % Add circle around here
      (0.90, 0.15)
    };
    % plot 1 legend entry
    %\addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=plot_one}
   \addlegendentry{D 3}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can add lines within the `axis` environment using:

`\draw (axis cs:x1,y1)--(axis cs:x2,y2);`

With (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) the coordinates of your lines.

2. In the `axis` environment, you can fill the area between paths. Start by creating paths:

`\path[name path = name_of_your_path] (axis cs:x1,y1) -- (axis cs:x2,y2);`

Then fill the area between two paths:

`\addplot [your_color] fill between[of = name_of_your_path_1 and name_of_your_path_2, soft clip = {domain=x1:x2}];`

Here, the two paths are defining the boundaries of the area on the y axis and the `soft clip` is defining the boundaries on the x axis.

3. For the points you are trying to circle, simply use a different marker by loading in the preamble:

`\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}`

Then select the appropriate marker. In your case use `mark=oplus` instead of`mark=+`. A complete list of markers can be found in the [Manual for Packagepgfplots](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots_layers.pdf), section "Markers, Linestyles, (Background-) Colors and Colormaps" (page 120 for the version 1.5.1 DEV).